# How to get the Key Pair value from a json file?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

data = "[{"id":"abc, "content":"Bye", "child": [{"id":"dsd", "parent id": "abc", "content": "dds"}]}, {"id": xcv, "content": "hello"}]"

```
   with open("data.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f)

    # reads it back
    with open("data.json","r") as f:
        parsed_json = json.load(f)

    for e in parsed_json:
        print (e["content"])
```

I would like to extract Bye and hello but i stumble upon this error. Was wondering how to loop through

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1aa8088c77a7> in <module>
     46 
     47     for e in parsed_json:
---> 48         print (e["content"])
     49 
     50 

TypeError: string indices must be integer
```

Comment: You must provide a [mcve].

Comment: Is that `data` really part of your code? Is the entire `data` really enclosed in `" "`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `json.dump` to write a string to a file.  Use it to write a data structure (list, dictionary, etc.) to a file.

So, don't put the original value for your `data` variable inside quotes.

Also, you're missing some of the quotes in the data (`abc` is missing the closing quote, and `xcv` is missing both quotes).

```
import json

data = [{"id":"abc", "content":"Bye", "child": [{"id":"dsd", "parent id":"abc", "content":"dds"}]}, 
        {"id":"xcv", "content":"hello"}]

with open("data.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f)

# reads it back
with open("data.json","r") as f:
    parsed_json = json.load(f)

for e in parsed_json:
    print (e["content"])
```